# How to make tabs visible in whole application?

Tags: android, tabs

I am developing an android application in which i have created five tabs and when i click any of the tab a new activity is called ,
my problem is

like i go from one tab to another tab and a new activity is called ,till then the tabs are visible but when i go to next activity from that activity the tabs disappear ,
all tabs are visible on five activity which are called on tabs but not in the inner activites like

Activity1 ---- > Activity2 ---- -----> Activity3

my question is how can i make the tabs visible in all the activities in the application

Comment: And you need to work on accept work also. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ActivityGroup` is deprecated, I suggest you use `Fragment`s and the `ActionBar`. Use the compt lib to support older versions of Android.

The [sdk samples has a good example you can refer to.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html)

Comment: You don't have to delete your answer, it can be helpful for people who want to use it.